# Get rid of gaps between bars in a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have this [dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwi9j3k4taxkbxs/df.csv?dl=0)! and wish to make a barplot from it.

I got the following code going with ggplot which produces almost the desired results, safe for the fact that I don't want there to be any space between the bars, vis-a-vis - the x-axis to be with a minimum amount of space between the data points.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = picsCRBBCH$count, x = picsCRBBCH$bbch, fill = picsCRBBCH$code_surveyed), data = picsCRBBCH,stat="identity")+
  scale_x_continuous("BBCH stages", labels = as.character(picsCRBBCH$bbch), breaks = picsCRBBCH$bbch)+
  #scale_x_discrete(limits = c('0', '1', '2', '3', '4'))
  ylab('Number of pictures')+ 
  labs(fill = "Crop")
```

[image: a busy cat]

I tried `scale_x_discrete`, but couldn't make it work. Does anybody have a hack?

Comment: You could turn your bbch variable into a (ordered) factor. It's a hack nontheless, I'm not sure if there is a way to not display the gaps of a nureic scale. Probably not, since it seems to go against the grammar.

Comment: agree with mgiormenti. just replace picsCRBBCH$bbch by as.factor(picsCRBBCH$bbch) in your code above  and replace scale_x_continuous by scale_x_discrete. That should do the trick.

Comment: That was it - the combo of `factor` and `scale_x_discrete`. Thank you gentlemen/ladies!